# Multiple circles filled with linear gradients background

Tags: css, background

I need to achieve this background pattern :

[image]

*I add to erase some text parts for clarification, ignore my poor Gimp skills*

I've been using a div for each circle but it doesn't feel very maintainable neither responsive. I was wondering if there was a pure CSS solution or if I should go for a SVG background.

Here is what I came up with for now : https://jsfiddle.net/ygvdckLf/15/

HTML

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="circles-container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.card {
  background: #6ec8d0;
  width: 274px;
  height: 132px;
}

.circles-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;

  &:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: -50%;
    left: 2%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,.3), transparent);
  }

  &:nth-child(2) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 20%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(50deg, rgba(255,255,255,.5), transparent 70%);
  }

  &:nth-child(3) {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    left: 60%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(20deg, rgba(255,255,255,.3), transparent 80%);
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      top: -50%;
      left: 60%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,.3), transparent);
    }
}
```

Any clue anyone ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use multiple background and radial gradient instead of linear

Comment: I've tried that but the gradients inside the cirlces are actually linear and there is no way that I know of drawing circles gradient filled in a linear way

Comment: the idea is to create a radial-gradient with a transaprent circle, and behind a linear gradient

Comment: I will try this that's a great idea ! thanks